# NodeAffinity doesn't work on Kubernetes 1.23+ and PG Pods are deployed on *unlabeled* Kubernetes Nodes

Tags: postgresql, kubernetes, kubectl, k3s

We have a Cluster of `4` nodes ,let's call them `node1 ,node2 ,node3 ,node4`.

**Kubernetes version**: 1.23.14+k3s.

**Requirement**: Deploy `2` of my PostgreSQL Pods (MASTER/SLAVE) on **node3** and **node4**.

I labeled and tainted **node3** and **node4** with:

```
kubectl label nodes node3 type=postgres
kubectl label nodes node4 type=postgres
kubectl taint nodes node3 type=postgres:NoSchedule
kubectl taint nodes node4 type=postgres:NoSchedule
```

Here are my nodes with their labels (Notice **type=postgres** on **NODE3/4**)

```
NAME   STATUS   ROLES                  AGE   VERSION         LABELS
node1   Ready    control-plane,master        v1.23.14+k3s1   ......................
node2   Ready    <none>                      v1.23.14+k3s1   ......................
node3   Ready    <none>                      v1.23.14+k3s1   kubernetes.io/hostname=node3,kubernetes.io/os=linux,node.kubernetes.io/instance-type=k3s,type=postgres
node4   Ready    <none>                      v1.23.14+k3s1   kubernetes.io/hostname=node4,kubernetes.io/os=linux,node.kubernetes.io/instance-type=k3s,type=postgres
```

This is the Affinity that I'm using on PostgreSQL Deployment:

```
    tolerations:
    - key: "type"
      operator: "Equal"
      value: "postgres"
      effect: "NoSchedule"
    nodeAffinity:
      requiredDuringSchedulingIgnoredDuringExecution:
        nodeSelectorTerms:
          - matchExpressions:
              - key: type
                operator: In
                values:
                  - postgres
```

Now the problem is that when I deploy the entire Namespace with all its pods , the `PG` (Postgres) pods (Master/Slave) are deployed to `node1/node2` and nothing is deployed on
`node3/node4`.

Events say that:
`0/4 nodes are available: 2 Insufficient memory, 2 node(s) had taint {type: postgres}, that the pod didn't tolerate.`

Why is this happening ?

Answer (score 0):

Since you are tainting 2 nodes, the scheduler is not taking them in consideration when trying to schedule your pods.

The nodeAffinity helps you to filter the nodes your pods could be scheduled on, but again, the taints will tell the scheduler to discard them.

You'll have to tell the scheduler that your pods will tolerate the taint, and you can do it with tolerations:

```
    tolerations:
    - key: "type"
        operator: "Equal" 
        effect: "NoSchedule"
        value: "postgres"
```

Comment: Same behavior , the `PG` pods still go on NODES `1` and `2` .